# How to access req.session in nextServerInit before rendering

Tags: express, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am setting up a website base on nuxt+express with cmd 'vue init nuxt-community/express-template'.The functionality i am working on is "auth".I am trying to get the session while i refresh the page so that to keep the store correctly(Just for user info).

After config the session(the middleware i use is 'express-session'), I set the session after 'login successfully' and console it correctly.However when i console the req.session in method nuxtServerInit, it gives me a 'undefined'.

```
// express-api
router.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const userQuery = await User.findOne({
      username,
      password: md5(password)
    }).exec();
    if (userQuery) {
      req.session.user = userQuery
      console.log(req.session)
      return ResUtils.success(res, userQuery);

// store actions
nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { req, res }) {
  console.log(req.session)
  commit('initUserInfo', req.session.user)
```

I expect to get req.session.user with which i can initialize the store after refresh the page. unfortunately, req.session is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this in your server/index.js or server/app.js basically wherever you create your express instance

```
// Create express router
const router = express.Router()

// Transform req & res to have the same API as express
// So we can use res.status() & res.json()
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(req, app.request)
  Object.setPrototypeOf(res, app.response)
  req.res = res
  res.req = req
  next()
})
```